# How to show phone number on the EditText from phone contacts?

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts, phone-number

This code send me a message. and the contacts button to retrieve the contacts from the phone contact is not working properly. can only read the contact, but when select do not want to appear on the `EditText`. there is an error message

```
Unfortunately.SMS Encryption has stopped
```

I do not know where the harm.

**form_create.java**

```
public class form_create extends Activity {

protected static final int RQS_PICK_CONTACT = 1;
private EditText NoTujuan;
private String id, name; 


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.form_create);

    final Button enkripButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEncrypt);
    final EditText inputKunci = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtKey);
    final EditText inputPesan = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
    final EditText teksEnkrip = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtMesEncrypt);
    final Button sendButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
    final Button mAddContact = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnContact);
    NoTujuan =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPhone);


    //button enkripsi
    enkripButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String ambilKunci = inputKunci.getText().toString();
            String ambilPesan = inputPesan.getText().toString();
            String enPesan = "";


            if(ambilKunci.length()==0){
                Toast.makeText(form_create.this, "Key must be filled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if
            (ambilKunci.length()>0 && ambilPesan.length()>0){
                try {
                    enPesan = GenerateAES.encrypt(ambilKunci, ambilPesan);
                    }   
                    catch (Exception e) {}
                    teksEnkrip.setText(enPesan);
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(form_create.this, "Text can not be empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }           
            }

           }    
       );

  //button kirim
    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        String  no = NoTujuan.getText().toString().trim();
        String  pesanEnkrip = teksEnkrip.getText().toString();

            try{
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(no, null, pesanEnkrip, null, null);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS SENT",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS FAILED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }               
        }

        private void Kirim_Pesan(String phoneNo, String message) {
            String SENT ="SMS_SENT";
            String DELIVERED="SMS_DELIVERED";

            PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);
            PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0, new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

            //ketika sms akan dikirim
            registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {

                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                    switch (getResultCode()) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS SENT", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;

                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS FAILED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;

                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Signal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), " Null PDU", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    }

                }
            }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

            registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {

                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                    switch (getResultCode()) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS SENT", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;

                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS FAILED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    }

                }
            }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            //sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(NoTujuan, null, teksEnkrip, sentPI, deliveredPI);
            ArrayList<String> parts = sms.divideMessage(message);
            sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNo, null, parts, null, null);
        }});

//Button Contact
mAddContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(i, 1);
            }
        });
    }
    //proses pengambilan kontak
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            getContactData(data);
        }
    }

    public void getContactData(Intent data)
    {

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

        Uri contactData = data.getData();
        Log.v("Contact", contactData.toString());
        Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);

        if (c.moveToFirst())
        {
            //ambil id contact
            id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            Log.v("Contact", "ID: " + id.toString());
            name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            Log.v("Contact", "Name: " + name.toString());

            //cek jumlah nomor pada contact yg dipilih
            if (Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0)
            {
                Cursor pCur = cr.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] {id}, null);

                while (pCur.moveToNext())
                {
                    //ambil nomor berdasarkan id yang dipilih
                    String phone = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    String type = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
                    String s = (String) ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.getTypeLabel(getResources(), Integer.parseInt(type), "");

                    Log.d("TAG", s + " phone: " + phone);
                    Log.d("TAG", s + " type: " + type);
                    Log.d("TAG", s + " s: " + s);
                    // tampilkan nomor
                    NoTujuan.setText(" " +phone);

                }

                pCur.close();
            }       }       
}}
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "but when select do not want to appear on the EditText"?

Comment: when i select a contact, number doesn't appear. and there is an error message "Unfortunately.SMS Encryption has stopped" then back to the main menu. can you help me?